# setting toilet flange in concrete

Tags: toilet

i am trying to rough out a waste line for the toilet in concrete.. what I am not sure about is how do I get he pvc flange to sit straight and flush if I pitch the pipe 1/2 inch to the stack

Comment: I think the drain pipe is supposed to pitch 1/4" per foot; apparently more than that is not optimal since the water can leave solids behind.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little flex in the PVC joints that will allow a little give to get it to set flush. If it is still a little off, the toilet does not set directly on the flange and the wax ring makes the seal. If the flange is up a little on one side in spite of all efforts you can "shim" it with grout or thinset, or perhaps a small wood shim.